# Run conda inside singularity

Tags: dockerfile, conda, singularity-container

I would like to run a conda command with singularity.
The command is:

```
singularity exec ~/dockerimage.sif conda
```

It yields an error:

```
/.singularity.d/actions/exec: 9: exec: conda: Permission denied
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils wget=1.20.3-1ubuntu1 python3.8=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2 python3-pip=20.0.2-5ubuntu1 python3-yaml=5.3.1-1  git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && chmod +x Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && ./Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && cp /root/miniconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda
RUN wget https://data.qiime2.org/distro/core/qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && conda env create -n qiime2-2020.8 --file qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && conda install -y -n qiime2-2020.8 -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c qiime2 -c defaults q2cli q2template q2-types q2-feature-table q2-metadata vsearch snakemake
```

What should I add to the Dockerfile? How would it work?

Answer (score 2):

You're installing with conda default settings, which puts it in the home of the current user. That user is `root`. Singularity runs as your current user, so unless you're running as root the conda files will not be available.

1. modify your conda install command to set the install prefix: `-p /opt/conda` (or some other arbitrary location)
2. make sure that any user will be able to access the files installed with conda: `chmod -R o+rX /opt/conda`
3. update `PATH` to include conda: `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/conda/bin"`
4. when running your image make sure your environment variables are not overriding those in the container: `singularity exec --cleanenv ~/dockerimage.sif conda`